# How to let this download to run async

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, download

I'm downloading a file with:

```
Public WithEvents mclient As New WebClient
   Private Sub Download()
       Label2.Text = "I am downloading"
       Label2.Refresh()
       Dim filepath As String = (path+filename+".mp3")
       mclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
       ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       mclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "")
       mclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(link), filepath)
   End Sub
```

And while it is downloading:

```
     Private Sub mClient_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadProgressChanged
   ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
            Label1.Text = (Val(e.BytesReceived) / Val(e.TotalBytesToReceive)).ToString("0.00") & "MB Downloaded"
            Label2.Text = "Downloading"
            Label2.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

To know when download finished I'm using:

```
     Private Sub mClient_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadFileCompleted
            Label2.Text = "Download completed"
            Label2.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

This code was working for a bit, but today, I re opened the project, ran it, but the form is kind of freezing/unfreezing. It is weird because the download is async, and the events.
Why is it doing like that if the download is async?
Thanks

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem..

Comment: Is download working without freeze the form for you?

Comment: Yes, I set a timer at 100ms to put a new guid in a label 10 times a second and also wired the download progress event up to a progress bar value and downloaded a 300mb file. The progress bar moved smoothly and the guids were flowing at 10 per second in the label, no freezing at all